# google chart script generates unexpected error

Tags: google-apps-script

Everytime i try to load a chart from the data i have it says "unexpected error".

I've loaded data from a datasheet with 1480 rows. Adding it the chart by the google menu works flawlessly.

when i add it throught script, it fails with the following error:
"Error encountered: An unexpected error ocurred"

```
function doGet() {

   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
   var lastrow = (sheet.getLastRow());
   // Get the range of cells that store mining data.
   var mining = ss.getRange("A2:H"+lastrow);

   // For every row of mining data, generate a mining object.
   var miningObjects = getRowsData(sheet, mining);



     var dataload = Charts.newDataTable();
     dataload.addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.STRING, "Date");
     dataload.addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, "Hash");
     for(var i = 0; i<miningObjects.length;i++){
       var support = miningObjects[i]
       //Browser.msgBox(Utilities.formatDate(support.date, "GMT-4", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm")+"")
       dataload.addRow([Utilities.formatDate(support.date, "GMT-3", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm")+"", support.hash])

     }
         dataload.build();
     var lineChart = Charts.newLineChart()
         .build();

        var control = Charts.newStringFilter()
        .setFilterColumnLabel("Date")
        .build();


     var dashboard = Charts.newDashboardPanel()
         .setDataTable(dataload)
         .bind(control, lineChart)
         .build();

     var uiApp = UiApp.createApplication();

     dashboard.add(uiApp.createVerticalPanel()
                   .add(uiApp.createHorizontalPanel()
                           .add(lineChart)
                           .setSpacing(10)));

         uiApp.add(dashboard);
         ss.show(uiApp);

}
```

original spreadsheet is here. for testing purposes i'm only using the first two rows.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AsNSSsm28wUfdFFKRU5SaFdKWkhNVWw0dTlPbXJvOVE&usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like there is a few things going on here. Not sure if you really want the `control` filter on a date. However, in the interest of just getting this working for you - you need to also add the filter control to the `dashboard`. See the `.add(control)` below.

```
  dashboard.add(uiApp.createVerticalPanel()
                .add(uiApp.createHorizontalPanel()
                     .add(control)
                     .add(lineChart)
                     .setSpacing(10)));
```